# How to resuse deleted model id number in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Say I have a Post model. When I delete last post 'Post 24', I want the next post to take id of Post 24 and not Post 25.

I want to show id in views and I don't want missing numbers. How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note: when asking for SQL answers, it is helpful to state what type you are using (mysql, sqlserver, oracle, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of an id is to be nothing more than an internal identifier.  It shouldn't be used publicly at all.  This isn't a Rails thing, but a database issue.  MySQL won't reclaim id's because it can lead to very serious complications in your app.  If a record is deleted, its id is laid to rest forevermore, so that no future record will be mistaken for it.

However, there is a way to do what you want.  I believe you want a `position` integer column instead.  Add that to your model/table, and then install the [acts_as_list plugin](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_list/).

Install it the usual way:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/acts_as_list.git
```

Then add the "hook" to your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list
end
```

Now the `position` column of your post model will automatically track itself, with no sequence gaps.  It'll even give you some handy methods for re-ordering if you so choose.

Comment: +1 this is exactly the answer I was thinking of reading the question, including using acts_as_list.

Comment: Ah I see...I wanted to show what number the post was in my Archives column. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you already have a different integer column to use, or you don't want to call it position, you can call the hook with a parameter: "acts_as_list :column => 'archive'", for example.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, you could let the SQL do this itself:

```
SELECT rownum AS id, [whatever other columns you want]
FROM posts_table
WHERE [conditions]
ORDER BY [ordering conditions]
```

This will add numbers to each row without skipping any like you said.

NOTE: I use Oracle.  I don't know if this exact code will work in other flavors.